# using POST to change an XML file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath

So I'm working on a new tool for my office to use, which is basically just a web page that renders a map of the office with some extra functionality. My confusion comes in why I try to make it editable.

The server I was given to work with has ASP.NET(2.0.50727) on it, and I figured I would use that.

Basically, each part of the map is editable(offices, printers, walls, etc). When you click one(assuming you are on the admin page), it brings up a simple HTML form with all the appropriate fields. Click "Apply", and it POSTs that to the .aspx page, which is supposed to alter the relevant XML document, and then forward you back to the map.

What I can't seem to figure out, is the entirety of ASP.NET. After searching/experimenting for days, I've got nothing. So far, I've been able to make this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body><%
dim format
format=Request.Form("Format") 'The format of the thing being edited. determines which .xml file to use
If format<>"" Then
      Response.Write(format)
End If

dim objectID
objectID=Request.Form("objectID")
If objectID<>"" Then
      Response.Write(objectID)
End If
XmlSource.XPath = format+"s/"+format+"[@objectID='"+objectID+"']"
XmlSource.DataFile = format+"s.xml"
%>
<form id="Form1" runat="server" >

      <asp:XmlDataSource
        runat="server"
        ID="XmlSource"
        EnableViewState="True"
        EnableCaching="False" />

      <asp:Repeater
        runat="server"
        ID="Repeater1"
        DataSourceID="XmlSource" >
          <ItemTemplate >
            <h1><%# XPath ("@type") %> </h1>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But it either spits out *every* node's "`type`" if I set the XPath & Datafile manually, or spits out: '`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`' if I try to make it dynamic(I have multiple formats like room, wall, printer, etc, and each has it's own XML file), which is what is needed.

I'm just looking for some guidance here, as I have no idea what I'm doing. Any ideas?

EDIT: Figured it out for the most part. Here is my new code:

```
<%@ Page LANGUAGE="VB" SMARTNAVIGATION="false" debug="true"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>

<script runat="server" >

  Private Sub Page_Load

    dim format
    format=Request.Form("format")
    If format<>"" Then
      Response.Write(format)
    End If
    XmlSource.DataFile = format+"s.xml"

    dim newObjectIDFromPOST
    newObjectIDFromPOST=Request.Form("objectID")
    If newObjectIDFromPOST<>"" Then
      Response.Write(newObjectIDFromPOST)
    End If

    dim oldObjectIDFromPOST
    oldObjectIDFromPOST=Request.Form("oldObjectID")
    If oldObjectIDFromPOST<>"" Then
      Response.Write(oldObjectIDFromPOST)
    End If

    Dim myXml As New XmlDocument

    myXml = CType(XmlSource.GetXmlDocument(), XmlDocument)
    Dim path As String = format+"s/"+format+"[@objectID='"+oldObjectIDFromPOST+"']"
    Dim node As XmlNode = myXml.SelectSingleNode(path)

    If format = "room" Then
      node.Attributes("objectID").Value = newObjectIDFromPOST
    End If

    XmlSource.Save()
    Repeater1.DataBind()

  End Sub 'on page load
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server" >

      <asp:XmlDataSource
        runat="server"
        ID="XmlSource"
        EnableViewState="True"
        EnableCaching="False" />

        <asp:Repeater
        runat="server"
        ID="Repeater1"
        DataSourceID="XmlSource" >
          <ItemTemplate >
            <h1><%# XPath ("@objectID") %> </h1>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: For clarification, you have a visual representation of your office. Clicking on an item in this representation brings up a form allowing you to edit information for the selected object. The updated information is saved to an XML file (per item)?

Comment: Almost. It's per *type* of item. So all "room" objects are contained in "rooms.xml". The saving part doesn't work yet though, as I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: If I was doing this, I'd use HTML and CSS to layout the room and objects, then add JavaScript click events to the objects which would display a modal form. On saving the form, I'd use Ajax to send the form data to a web service on the server. The server would then alter the rooms.xml file and return success/ failure to the calling Ajax function.

Comment: OK, so how does one go about that?

Comment: Do you have to use .net 2 or could you use 4.x and mvc?

Comment: I have to use .net 2. It's a super old machine. :C

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

General debugging: What is output from the following lines in your page?

```
Response.Write(format)

Response.Write(objectID)
```

How about when you add the following couple lines? (We need to find the object that is null, and causing the error.)

```
XmlSource.XPath = format+"s/"+format+"[@objectID='"+objectID+"']"
Response.Write("[" + XmlSource.XPath + "]")
XmlSource.DataFile = format+"s.xml"
Response.Write("[" + XmlSource.DataFile + "]")
```

Comment: Actually I think I just figured it out, at least for setting attributes on the starting level. I've updated my code up top. I should at least be able to make my way from here. Thanks for your help though!